# Fonts are misaligned vertically when using @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using an @font-face CSS rule to use a custom font (Old Sans Black) on my page. However, the font comes out completely out of alignment vertically. It looks fine when I install the font locally instead of using @font-face.

The issue occurs in Firefox, Chrome, and IE (although it looks better in IE :| ). Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HENGd.png

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you look at the first line of the paragraph under the heading, the bottom of each letter isn't aligned (it should be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. I've seen a question recently that was basically the same. I used to use Font-Face and after having things like that happening I started using Cufon. I can't believe I used to think it was hard to use. Compared to font-face, the quality is so much better. You should check it out.

Look at the difference:

http://mesonprojekt.com/blog/cufon-vs-font-face-a-visual-comparision

Comment: I will definitely try this. Having used Sifr, @font-face, and Google fonts, I've never heard of cufon before, but it looks like a very elegant solution.

Comment: I re-implemented everything with Cufon, and after 5 minutes of work, everything worked on the first try. My fonts look *awesome*, much better than any other solutions.. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: great!I m happy I know about it too now. I used Font-face a lot and when I found that article, It changed my life!not that much...